# C# UTF-8 base64 encoding doesn't decode correctly in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encoding, base64, urlencode

so I have the following problem: I'm encoding a file's contents in C# with UTF-8 into base64, then URL-encoding it and sending a GET request to my php, then I   url decode it there and then base64 decode it. The outcome is not 1:1 to the file I encoded in C#, no matter what. I've tried all encodings in C#, neither of them work. Am I supposed to do something else here? I'd also like to mention that I'm echoing back the file into an octet stream, perhaps echo can't "echo" UTF-8 characters?

Here's my Base64 Encoding in C#:

```
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
         var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
         string base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
         return WebUtility.UrlEncode(base64);
    }
```

Here's how I decode it in PHP:

```
base64_decode(urldecode($_GET["parameter"]));
```

And here's how I'm downloading it:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<filename>"');
echo(base64_decode(urldecode($_GET["parameter"])));
```

Thanks.

Comment: no code, no help.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: Yeah, I've just fixed that - still no luck.

Comment: Have you got a short failure case?

Comment: What do you mean by "short failure case", a sample file?

Comment: I mean a short example that doesn't work. Are the files you're dealing with human-readable?

Comment: I'm dealing with files, and they're definitely not human readable, they've got tons of weird characters. I can give you an example file if needed.

Comment: Where does `plainText` come from?

Comment: I read the file with StreamReader, and I use .ReadToEnd().

Comment: I'd skip the encoding altogether and just use `File.ReadAllBytes()`, and then you can do something along the lines of `Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(fileName))`. It may be that you have data which doesn't encode well with UTF8, so I'd skip that if you can.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying that, I'll get back with the results in a couple minutes, thanks for helping me.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine, if you leave an answer I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading the file as a string, and then converting it back to binary in order to convert it to a base64 string, you could simply read the file as bytes:

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

And then convert this to base64:

```
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```